# URL gets truncated when accessing it using wget or curl

Tags: shell, cron, wget, curl

I have a web CMS that allows so-called action IDs, which are URLs. When these action IDs are accessed, they perform some action within the CMS.

I wanted to perform an action periodically and used cron for that purpose. Even though the cron always ran at the defined time, which I could track in the log, the action was never performed.

To troubleshoot this, I tested the URL, `http://172.16.0.47/index.php?ACT=47&id=6`, in the shell environment.

However, when I used `wget`, it cut off the `&id=6` parameter. The same thing happened when I used `curl`.

I'm looking for a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the URL in single-quotes. What is happening is that the ampersand is getting interpreted by the shell.

```
curl 'http://172.16.0.47/index.php?ACT=47&id=6'
```

Without the quotes (assuming you are using a shell configured to *not* error out on unmatched globbing patterns), you would start the command

```
curl http://172.16.0.47/index.php?ACT=47
```

... as a background job, and then set the shell variable `id` to the string `6`.