# URL ampersand escape xdg-open command

Tags: bash, escape-characters, url, xdg-open

I am trying to open a URL using the `xdg-open` command, but I have tried escaping the ampersand character to no avail; all possible choices don't work in bash.

I have tried the following

```
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream" <-works fine as desired
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream&as_epq=cream+here" <- problem arises here due to ampersand
```

I tried to escape it using following methods

```
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream\&as_epq=cream+here"
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream^&as_epq=cream+here"
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream%26as_epq=cream+here"
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream&amp;as_epq=cream+here"
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream\&amp;as_epq=cream+here"
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream+%26+as_epq=cream+here"
xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream&&as_epq=cream+here"
```

But in no case, the response is similar to what it should be when the URL `https://google.co.in?q=cream&as_epq=cream+here` is typed in the browser.

Please help to get the correct way to execute xdg-open with escaping the ampersand.

Comment: What problem arises with `xdg-open "https://google.co.in?q=cream&as_epq=cream+here"`? It works for me.

Comment: For me, it opens the chrome with "https://google.co.in?q=cream"; the rest of the get parameter after ampersand are dropped.

Comment: What about single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: I'd expect that you get the behaviour described in comments if you do not quote the URL (similar to [curl and wget cut off url](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231006)), but you do quote the URL in the question. Please try again with the command in your question and update the question with the actual issue (i.e. what you mean by "don't work").